# ng-token-auth passwordResetSuccessUrl not redirecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise

I am building a rails app with AngularJs on the front end. When resetting a users' password, the email sends as expected, however the reset link does not redirect to the configured `passwordResetSuccessUrl` and simply goes to: 
`http://localhost:8000/auth/password/edit?reset_password_token=KNsWjzizNWNsMqzSss8F`

As you can see, the `redirect_url` is not there, should I see it in the url? Also, when clicking through the link, the app does not fire the `auth:password-reset-confirm-success` event as noted in ng-token-auth documentation.

here's the request:
`{"email":"myemail@gmail.com","redirect_url":"http://localhost:8000/#!/updatePassword"}`

the response is a 500 error (i find this odd, the email is sent and no error in the server log) with the message:
{"message":"password reset email sent"}

Here's some relevant configuration code:

```
function authConfig($authProvider,envServiceProvider) {
    let url = envServiceProvider.is('development') ? 'http://localhost:8000' : 'https://miles-board.herokuapp.com';

    $authProvider.configure([{
           'default': {
                apiUrl: url,
                emailRegistrationPath: '/users',
                confirmationSuccessUrl: window.location.href,
                validateOnPageLoad: false,
                passwordResetSuccessUrl: url+'/#!/updatePassword'
            }},
            {'user': {
                apiUrl: url,
                emailRegistrationPath: '/users',
                confirmationSuccessUrl: window.location.href,
                validateOnPageLoad: false,
                passwordResetSuccessUrl: url+'/#!/updatePassword'
            }},
            {'team_owner' : {
                apiUrl: url,
                emailRegistrationPath: '/team_owners',
                confirmationSuccessUrl: window.location.href,
                validateOnPageLoad: false,
                passwordResetSuccessUrl: url+'/#!/updatePassword'
            }
        }]
    );
    console.log('is dev: ', envServiceProvider.is('development'))
}
```

I had issues with the email confirmation, as well, so I assume I've missed something in my set up, but I'm not sure what.

Being new to rails, I have to ask a very newbie question: I have the `devise_token_auth` gem installed, do I need to install `devise` as well, or does the `devise_token_auth` include that?

In my `devise_token_auth.rb` intializer, I have included this as well:
`config.default_password_reset_url = 'http://localhost:8000/#!/updatePassword'`

Please let me know if there's any other information I can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got this working, here's what I had to do go get it working with an AngularJS front end and Rails back:

Override the **PasswordsController** `create`, `update`, `edit`, and `after_resetting_password_path_for`

For the `create` and `update` functions, the primary issue was that I needed it to render a json response, so where it says something like `respond_with resource` I changed to `render json: resource, status: <status>, && return` (you can change resource and status to what you need for your application, same with the render method)

For `edit`, instead of using `after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for`, I grabbed the redirect URL from the email and simply do a `redirect_to params[:redirect_url]`

and I changed `after_resetting_password_path_for` to redirect where I want the user to be logged in to.

I also had to change the `reset_password_instructions.html.erb` template. the line which contains **edit_password_url** to this:

```
<p><%= link_to t('.password_change_link'), edit_password_url(@resource, reset_password_token: @token, config: 'default', redirect_url: message['redirect-url'].to_s+'?reset_token='+@token).html_safe %></p>
```

Then in `routes.rb`, I had to let devise know to use my controller:

```
mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', controllers: { passwords: 'passwords' }
```

I'm not thrilled about the redirect URL portion in edit, it has a code smell to it that I don't exactly like, but it works. If some one has advice on that front, I would appreciate it!